# Where can I find data on market capitalization?

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, stock-market, international-economics, bonds

I am working on Home Equity/Bond Bias and need data to calculate the indicators of Home Equity Bias. So where can I find data on market capitalization (stocks and bonds) by year for each country?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Market capitalization of listed domestic companies (% of GDP) across years and countries from the World Development Indicators in the [World Bank data website](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/CM.MKT.LCAP.GD.ZS) or the [United Nations one](http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=WDI&f=Indicator_Code%3ACM.MKT.LCAP.GD.ZS).
- [FRED economic data](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/tags/series?t=market%20cap) on market capitalization.
- Focusing on European Countries: the [ECB website](https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/browse.do?node=9691455).